# How to change aspx html heading from code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is my heading that i want to change from my c# code

```
 <h3>Please Enter a number between 1 &amp; 
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_max" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </h3>
```

I want to replace it with a string

```
string message = "This is new heading...";
```

i was thinking about something like this

```
lbl_max.value = message;
```

But it's not working... I am absolutely new to asp.net, so forgive me if it's a stupid question...

Comment: if you use mvc,  use model in View then @Html.LabelFor(m => m.lbl_max) replace <asp:Label .... or put value in var then <label id='lbl_max''>@:message</label>

Comment: This is webforms code as has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: The way you are doing looks correct. So you need to post the full code, like where are you setting the label, which event?

Comment: Do Something like this <asp:Label ID="lbl_max" runat="server" Tex=""></asp:Label> *** in c# lbl_max=message

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
this.lbl_max.Text = "This is new heading...";
```